# R, ggplot2 - In the legend, how do I hide unused colors from one geom while showing them in others?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a plot that has color defined for a `geom_point()`, and everything looks good.

```
points_a <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 4), y = sample(50:60, 4), id = "a")
points_b <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 4), y = sample(1:100, 4), id = "b")
points_c <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 4), y = sample(1:100, 4), id = "c")
points_all <- rbind(points_a, points_b, points_c)

ggplot(points_all) + geom_point(aes(x, y, color=id))
```

[image: ggplot with points]

I'd like to highlight a group of points by drawing a rectangle around them using `geom_rect()`, picking up the same color already used in the chart. As desired, the legend adds a border around the item in the key; unfortunately, it also adds a border to every other item in the legend, as shown below:

```
my_box <- data.frame(left = 1, right = 10, bottom = 50, top = 60, id = "a")
ggplot(points_all) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, color=id)) + 
  geom_rect(data = my_box, 
    aes(xmin=left, xmax=right, ymin=bottom, ymax=top, color = id), 
    fill = NA, alpha = 1)
```

[image: ggplot with points and rectangle]

I want to get rid of the outlines around items "b" and "c" in the legend, since they're not plotted. I don't know how to do that, since they're defined by the same color aesthetic as the points. Ideally these unused factors should have been dropped from the legend for the outline color, as they rightfully are when showing only one `geom_`, but that doesn't seem to be how it works. (And defining the color manually outside the `aes()` call means it wouldn't get shown on the legend for `id="a"`.)

Lots of searching hasn't yet yielded an answer, though I may have overlooked something. What's the best way to hide from the legend unused colors for one `geom_` while keeping them for others? (Alternatively: Should I split these into two legends, and how?)

Comment: Have you seen `geom_encircle()` from the ggalt package? 
https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt

Comment: Yes, I have, and it's very nice. But I'm still hopeful there's a general way to do this with something built in to ggplot, as the scenario described here is a simplified version of a more complicated scenario. (Among other things, I'm writing a function that will highlight by category the labels on a dendrogram, where a rectangular annotation makes more sense than something circular.)

Comment: For what it's worth, `geom_encircle()` suffers the same malady: every item in the legend gets a line added to it, even when only one is plotted. It's something to do with color aesthetics for two different geoms getting tangled up with each other.

Comment: Sounds like this will be a tough nut to crack, then.  Good luck!

Comment: I feel like there may be a newer way to do this, but the  "manual" way is usually `override.aes`.  In your case you can make the line type 0 for the groups you don't want the rectangles for: `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 0, 0) ) ) )`.

Comment: I know I had seen something about this.  It looks like there is discussion in [this Github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3648) about potentially easier ways to do this.  These haven't been implemented yet, but may be in the future.

Comment: @aosmith, you've saved the day! This is exactly what I was hoping for. I'd like to mark your suggestion as the answer, if you wouldn't mind putting it below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually tackle this sort of thing with `override.aes` in `guide_legend()`.  In your case you can set the line type for the last two legend items to be `0` (no line).  The first legend item should have linetype `1`.

```
ggplot(points_all) + 
     geom_point(aes(x, y, color=id)) + 
     geom_rect(data = my_box, 
               aes(xmin=left, xmax=right, ymin=bottom, ymax=top,
                   color = id), 
               fill = NA, alpha = 1) +
     guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 0, 0) ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

aosmith has a great answer above. Alternatively, you could split the legends by changing the aesthetic in `geom_point` to `fill` in a hollow point:

```
points_all %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = id), shape = 21, stroke = 0, size = 2.5) +
  geom_rect(
    data = my_box,
    aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, ymin = bottom, ymax = top, color = id),
    fill = NA, alpha = 1
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was at a point where I couldn't even strategize a working solution for separating the two legends.